# Running 32 bit apps in Catalina using Mojave libs and frameworks

Tags: catalina, 32-bit, dynamic-library

I recently read this [post](http://netkas.org/?p=1491) on netkas.org about running 32 bit command line apps on Catalina using Mojave 32+64bit libraries and frameworks, adding to the `nvram boot-args` the option `no32exec=0`.

I extracted with Pacifist the `/usr/lib`, `/System/Library/Frameworks` and `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks` folders from the Mojave installation app to ~/.mojave and then tried to run [this](http://www.macdatarecoveryfreeware.com) 32 bit macOS app with the following terminal command:

```
$ DYLD_ROOT_PATH=~/.mojave /Volumes/Lazesoft\ Mac\ Data\ Recovery/Lazesoft\ Mac\ Data\ Recovery.app/Contents/MacOS/Lazesoft\ Mac\ Data\ Recovery
```

Here is what I get running it:

```
2020-06-08 17:26:18.630 Lazesoft Mac Data Recovery[1881:56237] /Volumes/Lazesoft Mac Data Recovery/Lazesoft Mac Data Recovery.app
2020-06-08 17:26:18.630 Lazesoft Mac Data Recovery[1881:56237] /Volumes/Lazesoft Mac Data Recovery/Lazesoft Mac Data Recovery.app/Contents/MacOS/ifsui
2020-06-08 17:26:18.632 Lazesoft Mac Data Recovery[1881:56237] Error Creating Initial Authorization: -60008
2020-06-08 17:26:18.632 Lazesoft Mac Data Recovery[1881:56237] AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges failed!
```

Trying to run `ifsui` from the same app bundle I get the app to open in the dock but nothing appears on screen and this is what I get on the terminal:

```
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO REGISTER PROCESS WITH CPS/CoreGraphics in WindowServer, err=-304
2020-06-08 17:21:38.555 ifsui[1836:52747] *** WARNING: Method userSpaceScaleFactor in class NSView is deprecated on 10.7 and later. It should not be used in new applications. Use convertRectToBacking: instead.
```

I know I'm probably asking something that cannot really be done, but is there any way to make this workaround work with more than command-line programs?

Comment: maybe try running as root or using sudo. If that doesn't work maybe try in recovery mode?

Comment: Note the link talks about `command line apps ` You run these from the terminal, they never appear to the screen and can't write out any graphics to the screen

Comment: This won't be much of a consolation, but I got stuck at roughly the same spot trying to get Skitch 1.x to run on Catalina. The WindowServer error.